# how to find a part of a path using tcl?

Tags: tcl

I am farily new to tcl. I am trying to write a tcl script that will perform a few thins on certain files in a tree structure, but on *all* files.

I have in my tree a number of files ending with `.xci`.
Now I want to filter our all .gbn files except the ones in a part of my tree (i.e. `/src/ps/<a number of directories>/<a number of files>.xci`) that contains the path part "`/ps/`"

I have done this:

```
foreach xci_file [get_files *.xci] {
    #if (ps_is_found_in_path_of_${xci_file}) {
        generate_target simulation [get_files $xci_file]
    }
}
```

The foreach search through all files in my project and returns the filename (including the full path). How do I write the if statement to avoid target generation of the files whose paths include "`/ps/`"?

Is there a nice soul out there who could share some light on this?

Comment: (I was commenting on your elaboration which you removed, maybe I can put the comment here.) The `in` operator is for membership; the reverse operator is `ni` ("not in"). You can't add the slashes back, but you could do `[file split [file dirname $xci_file]]` to avoid looking at the filename part.

Answer (score 0):

You want:

```
if {"ps" in [file split $xci_file]} {
```

The quotes are required here: `expr` (which handles `if`'s first argument) 
needs literal strings quoted.

Comment: If the intention was to avoid, maybe it should be `ni` instead.

Comment: Yes - that was the intention. I forgot the word "not" above. I changed to "ni" and this seems to work. 

However, I have valid filenames that contains "ps" - what I really want is to filter out "/ps/" to make sure it is the directory ps that I mean. Can I add the "/"-characters just like that?

Comment: @Teddy: see my comment to the question.

Comment: expr's "in" operator uses, I think, string equality, so `expr {"ps" in {foo epsilon}}` returns false.